# How to update user password in Cognito user pool without old password using Amplify?

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

We have multistep register form where user can set their password in step 2.
(User register should happen in step1 itself) So, we will set random password during step 1 and registering user details in Cognito user pool.
But end user submitting actual password from step 2.
Cognito will not update password (from step 2) without sending old password (random generated from step1). Cognito considers this process will be password update.

So how we need to handle this situation? or Is there any option / tricks which amplify provides to overcome this case?

Answer (score 0):

More context is needed to fully understand why a random password is necessary for the user in this situation.

For example, if you are trying to create a multi-screen signup process and you don't want the user to get to the end of the process only to find out their password doesn't meet standards, e-mail already exists, etc., it may be more conducive to the user experience to check if the user already exists in the user pool **first** using [ListUsers](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cognito-idp/list-users.html), collect the data as they move through the steps, and finally call the [SignUp](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cognito-idp/sign-up.html) API call.

While I would highly recommend reconsidering the approach taken, the [AdminSetUserPassword](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cognito-idp/admin-set-user-password.html) is a backend API call that can be used to set a permanent password for the user, although extreme care should be taken with this method to prevent the API call from being used maliciously on another user.

Comment: Thank you. I see AdminSetUserPassword is better approach in my case.